# How to calculate TVirtualStringTree node data field

Tags: delphi, tvirtualstringtree

I have VirtualStringTree (VST) with nodes that have the next data structure :

```
Type
  PMyNodeData = ^TMyNodeData;
  TMyNodeData = record
    Cost:UnicodeString; 
  end;
```

The Child nodes which they don't have any children has Cost value but any parent nodes has cost value equaled to 0 and am trying to write procedure to make any parent node cost value equaled to sum of all its children cost .

I have tried the next :

```
procedure CalculateSum(Node:PVirtualNode);
var
  Data: PMyNodeData;
  ChildNode: PVirtualNode;
  ChildData: PMyNodeData;
  CostSum: Extended;
begin
  Data := VST.GetNodeData(Node);
  CostSum := 0.0;
  ChildNode := VST.GetFirstChild(Node);
  while Assigned(ChildNode) do
  begin
    ChildData := VST.GetNodeData(ChildNode);
    CostSum := CostSum + StrToFloat(ChildData.Cost);
    CalculateSum(ChildNode);
    ChildNode := VST.GetNextSibling(ChildNode);
  end;
  if  VST.HasChildren[Node] and (StrToFloat(Data.Cost) = 0) then
    Data.Cost := FloatToStr(CostSum);

end;
```

The use :

```
CalculateSum(vst.RootNode);
```

But I get Access violation & the sum is not correct .. any suggestions.

Comment: You need to visit children before summing so move CalculateSum() up a line. As for the access violation give the details or provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue as the next :

```
    procedure CalculateSum(Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  Data: PMyNodeData;
  ChildNode: PVirtualNode;
  ChildData: PMyNodeData;
  CostSum: Extended;
begin
  Data := VST.GetNodeData(Node);
  if data<>nil then
  CostSum := Data.Cost else Costsum:=0.0;
  ChildNode := VST.GetFirstChild(Node);
  while Assigned(ChildNode) do
  begin
    ChildData := VST.GetNodeData(ChildNode);
    if ChildData <> nil then
    begin
      CalculateSum(ChildNode);
      CostSum := CostSum + ChildData.Cost;
    end;
    ChildNode := VST.GetNextSibling(ChildNode);
  end;
  if (VST.HasChildren[Node]) and (Data<>nil) then
    Data.Cost := CostSum;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing a child's `Cost` before it has been calculated. You need to call `CalculateSum(ChildNode)` *before* adding its `Cost` to `CostSum`, rather than *after* as you are currently doing.

Also, you did not specify whether `PMyDataNode` is ever `nil`, or whether `TMyNodeData.Cost` contains a blank string for nodes whose value is 0. `StrToFloat()` will raise an exception if you give it a blank string. If that is a possibility, use `StrToFloatDef()` or `TryStrToFloat()` instead.

Try something more like this:

```
procedure CalculateSum(Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  Data, ChildData: PMyNodeData;
  ChildNode: PVirtualNode;
  Cost, CostSum: Extended;
begin
  if not VST.HasChildren[Node] then Exit;
  Data := VST.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Data = nil then Exit;
  CostSum := 0.0;
  ChildNode := VST.GetFirstChild(Node);
  while Assigned(ChildNode) do
  begin
    ChildData := VST.GetNodeData(ChildNode);
    if ChildData <> nil then
    begin
      CalculateSum(ChildNode);
      if TryStrToFloat(ChildData.Cost, Cost) then
        CostSum := CostSum + Cost;
      // or:
      // CostSum := CostSum + StrToFloatDef(ChildData.Cost, 0.0);
    end;
    ChildNode := VST.GetNextSibling(ChildNode);
  end;
  Data.Cost := FloatToStr(CostSum);
end;
```

That being said, I would suggest storing `TMyNodeData.Cost` as a `Double`/`Extended` instead of a `UnicodeString`. All of those conversions are just unnecessary overhead.

Try this instead:

```
Type
  PMyNodeData = ^TMyNodeData;
  TMyNodeData = record
    Cost: Extended; 
  end;

...

procedure CalculateSum(Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  Data, ChildData: PMyNodeData;
  ChildNode: PVirtualNode;
  CostSum: Extended;
begin
  if not VST.HasChildren[Node] then Exit;
  Data := VST.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Data = nil then Exit;
  CostSum := 0.0;
  ChildNode := VST.GetFirstChild(Node);
  while Assigned(ChildNode) do
  begin
    ChildData := VST.GetNodeData(ChildNode);
    if ChildData <> nil then
    begin
      CalculateSum(ChildNode);
      CostSum := CostSum + ChildData.Cost;
    end;
    ChildNode := VST.GetNextSibling(ChildNode);
  end;
  Data.Cost := CostSum;
end;
```

Comment: Actually yesterday I have changed the cost data type into `Extended` and changing the the last condtion to be as the next :  `if (VST.HasChildren[Node]) and (Data<>nil) then` and this solved the issue .